# Sudoku generator creates an infinite loop

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop, sudoku

I'm attempting to create code that generates a random sudoku board in Java. I've made three methods that check the row, columns, and squares. When I call them in my other method that places a random number in a cell, it creates an infinite loop. This is only, by the way, when they are considered in an if statement together. Each of them work individually, but together they make it infinite somehow. I realized that it could be possible that it's trying to create a board that simply isn't possible, but I have no idea how I can fix that. I would greatly appreciate help on this issue.

```
public static void fillBoard(int brd[][])
{
    for(int i = 0;i< brd.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<brd[i].length;j++)
        {
            int num = random();
            if(checkBoxes(brd,num,i,j)||checkRow(brd,num,i)||checkColumn(brd,num,j))
            {
                j--;
            }
            else
            {
                brd[i][j]=num;
            }
        }
    }
}
public static boolean checkRow(int arr[][],int cell,int row)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<arr[row].length;i++)
    {
        if(arr[row][i]==cell)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean checkColumn(int ary [][],int cell,int column)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<=8;i++)
    {
        if(ary[i][column]==cell)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean checkBoxes(int boa [][],int cell,int row, int column)
{
    if(column==0||column==3||column==6)
    {
        if(row==0||row==3||row==6)
        {
            for(int i=row;i<=row+2;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column;j<=column+2;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(row==1||row==4||row==7)
        {
            for(int i=row-1;i<=row+1;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column;j<=column+2;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(row==2||row==5||row==8)
        {
            for(int i=row-2;i<=row;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column;j<=column+2;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(column==1||column==4||column==7)
    {
        if(row==0||row==3||row==6)
        {
            for(int i=row;i<=row+2;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column-1;j<=column+1;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(row==1||row==4||row==7)
        {
            for(int i=row-1;i<=row+1;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column-1;j<=column+1;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(row==2||row==5||row==8)
        {
            for(int i=row-2;i<=row;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column-1;j<=column+1;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(column==2||column==5||column==8)
    {
        if(row==0||row==3||row==6)
        {
            for(int i=row;i<=row+2;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column-2;j<=column;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(row==1||row==4||row==7)
        {
            for(int i=row-1;i<=row+1;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column-2;j<=column;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(row==2||row==5||row==8)
        {
            for(int i=row-2;i<=row;i++)
            {
                for(int j = column-2;j<=column;j++)
                {
                    if(cell==boa[i][j])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This line `j--;` is your problem. If a problem is encountered it will go back and just do it all over again. Rather than just going back one step and repeating the same thing all over again you need to go back and change something, and you may need to go back many more than one step as you get further into the puzzle and more cells are filled in.

Comment: Hint: Use a recursion tree to easily solve this problem, rather than nested for loops.  With recursion, if every node of a branch returns false it will go back to a previous branch automatically and pick another option.